# Dialogflow Detect Intent Matching Confidence And Entity Value Selection

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am looking to understand how detect intent confidence impacts entity value selection in Dialogflow. For example, using two user generated phrases:

- Phrase 1: "For snack yesterday I had an apple and peanut butter". This phrase has an intent detection confidence of '1' and 'snack' and 'yesterday' are tagged correctly to their respective entities, and the foods, 'apple' and 'peanut butter' are correctly matched within their entity [food], with values of 'apple' and 'peanut butter' respectively.
- Phrase 2: "Are the snack yesterday I had an apple and peanut butter". This phrase was mumbled by the user or garbled by Siri (we use an iOS voice app). Here the intent detection confidence is '0.852' and while 'snack' and 'yesterday' are tagged to their entities correctly, the foods are not treated as above. Specifically, while both are tagged to the correct entity [food] and 'apple' was correctly tagged to 'apple', the 'peanut' of 'peanut butter' was tagged as one food [value = 'peanut'] and the 'butter' of 'peanut butter' was tagged as another food [value = 'butter'].

As context we have ~500 intents, the intent matched above has ~400 training phrases (clearly not including 'Are the...') and ~200 entities, the largest of which has 29,998 values.

So it appears the intent detection confidence impacts the entity parameter value matching. Can anyone shed any light on this? From our viewpoint, it is not a useful 'feature'. Quite the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

When searching for a matching intent, Dialogflow scores potential matches with an intent detection confidence, also known as the confidence score.

These values range from 0.0 (completely uncertain) to 1.0 (completely certain). Without taking the other factors described in this document into account, once intents are scored, there are three possible outcomes:

- If the highest scoring intent has a confidence score greater than or equal to the ML Classification Threshold setting, it is returned as a match.
- If no intent meets the threshold, a fallback intent is matched.
- If no intents meet the threshold and no fallback intent is defined, no intent is matched.

**Update:** As per the GCP DialogFlow development team:
*Scores are referred to intent recognition confidence
Parameter extraction is not taken into account when scores are computed"
In other words, there is no relationship between intent classification confidence and entity extraction.*

The described behavior could potentially be a bug within DialogFlow or something specific to your GCP project and further inspection for your GCP project is required with GCP Support to investigate why this is happening. You can create a [GCP Support Case](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: I understand. My question is how the confidence score impacts entity item selection, and, if it does (as would appear to be the case), how this might be controlled.

Comment: I think you are looking for this [documentation](https://medium.com/voice-tech-global/machine-learning-confidence-scores-all-you-need-to-know-as-a-conversation-designer-8babd39caae7)

Comment: The documentation you reference highlights the relationship between the confidence score and intent matching. That is not my query. In my case the right intent is being matched (it is the same in both the examples I provided), but the entity value being extracted is different. It is like the confidence score is being used for entity param matching too. So rather than matching the entity param exactly (first case) it matches another value inexactly (second case).

Comment: This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-settings#priority) won't really answer the query you have, but could guide on how the priority is managed within dialogflow.

Comment: Eduardo, familiar with intent priority but it is off topic versus this question

Comment: Philip, I think that you might want to make use of [fuzzy matching](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-fuzzy), also could you share the training phrases from the intents and maybe and export of the agent?

Comment: Eduardo, I appreciate the thought but 'BTDT' with fuzzy matching. It was a nightmare and is not germane to the topic. We put massive effort into creating a dataset to enable precise matching of entity values. Enabling FL creates variability we can't control. Is anyone using FL with a complex NLP agent? The TP above are indicative. At its heart, my question is one of logic to the developers of DF.

Comment: @Philip0505 We made an internal GCP Support consult with the developers of DialogFlow and they stated:
Scores are referred to intent recognition confidence
Parameter extraction is not taken into account when scores are computed"
In other words, there is no relationship between intent classification confidence and entity extraction.

Comment: Eduardo, thanks for the follow up. The feedback from the DF developers confirms scores relate to intent detection confidence. Understand that. You go on to conclude, 'there is no relationship between intent classification confidence and entity extraction'. I can't draw that conclusion from what they have said and this goes to the heart of my question. We are finding that it does. Could you follow up with them explicitly on this point?

Comment: @Philip0505 As requested, we asked again and they said as a conclusion: “Entity recognition and intent confidence scores are not related”. They also understand you are experiencing unexpected behavior in your project. This is exactly why you would need to create a GCP Support Case to inspect why that is happening. Please use the link I posted in my answer above to create it.

Comment: Thank you for the extra step. Will do on the link and will post any resolution here when done

Answer (score 1):

Over the last few weeks we have interacted at some length with GCP Support who've interacted with the DF engineering team.

The short answer is they indicate the entity value extraction is 'as designed', and specifically, when using a composite entity (a nested entity structure), values that match input terms (here, 'peanut', 'butter' and 'peanut butter') are extracted and matched at random. So a user's utterance of 'peanut butter' may be matched to 'peanut' and 'butter' or 'peanut butter' at random.

This behavior cannot be controlled by adding additional training phrases to the agent.

From our point of view, the behavior is not as desired but we understand the implications for our design. Hopefully this 'answer' helps others navigate this and similar issues.